# Here is my code

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```js
private static final String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + UID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
  NAME + "VARCHAR(255);";
```

When I try to run it I will get the log error as following...!

04-17 12:35:38.057 17642-17642/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "table": syntax error

Im not getting where is syntax error in sql.

Comment: "I'm not getting where is syntax error in sql."  Really?  Did you look at the SQL?  The brackets don't balance!

Comment: I'd say missing whitespace is the problem that's keeping the parser from detecting the missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: `TABLE` is a reserved keyword. You can't use it for your table name. Next time post your **full** logcat. And some few **more lines of code**.

Comment: @StephenC  Oh my!! hmm silliest mistake!! -_-

Comment: btw code snippets are for web demos, not database connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

you have to close the Round Brackets of table

```
private static final String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
```

"(" + UID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
  NAME + "VARCHAR(255)  );";

Comment: Even though after modifying the code Im getting the following error..!        04-17 15:18:52.815 12392-12392/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Comment: UID is the name of table column or what? 
if it is the name of the column then write "UID INTEGER  primary key autoincrement"

Comment: same thing with the name

Comment: private static final String UID= "_id";                                                       private static final String CREATE_TAB = "CREATE TABLE"  +TABLE_NAME+"(" +UID+ "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +NAME+  "VARCHAR(255));";                                                                   Yes UID is the name of the column

Comment: 04-17 15:26:03.226 18618-18618/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sample.dbdemo-1/lib/x86
04-17 15:26:03.234 18618-18618/? I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.sample.dbdemo
04-17 15:26:03.833 18618-18618/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
04-17 15:26:03.977 18618-18648/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-17 15:26:03.977 18618-18648/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1